# PHP Switch True / False constant values

Tags: php, boolean, constants

Is there a way to switch the defined Constant values of true / false in PHP?  I am trying to make true = false and false = true.

I've tried several attempts to do this but it does not seem to allow me to change:

```
define("false",1);
define(false,1);
false = true;
```

The final one results in a PHP internal server error, the first two simply do nothing.

None of these seem to work.  Is true / false defined somewhere deeper within compiled PHP that cannot be re-set?

Note: this is mostly for educational purposes and to understand how these values are defined, since it appears to be "untouchable".  I am not trying to write blasphemous code that checks things in reverse.

Comment: No, you can't; and this is deliberate... and why by the great flying spaghetti monster would you want to?.... if you absolutely have to reverse the meaning of true and false for some obscure business logic, then you can use namespacing; or class constants

Comment: Well, sort of actually. The default constant is registered as "FALSE" internally, but case-insensitvely. Overloaded constants can be case-sensitive however, so `define("False", 1, 0);` would kindof work. But you're not able to override `false` because the lowercase/ci variant takes precedence.

Comment: @MarkBaker Like I noted in the question, it was purely educational because there is no documented reason anywhere that I could find.  Most other constants can be redefined but this cannot be.  I do understand that it would likely completely screw up all the parsing of statements such as '==', 'if', etc.  Thanks for the info on namespacing!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, so that you only can write `TRUE` and you will get FALSE. The only way, which would work is to use [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) if you defined both constants, e.g.

```
define(FALSE, TRUE);
define(TRUE, FALSE);
var_dump(constant(TRUE));
```

output:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, so I can improve and edit my answer

Comment: Means why the answer is downvoted? Without any reasons or clarification

Comment: Thanks @Rizier, I didn't realize that the constant() function showed the newly set value.  It is very interesting that it displays correct using Constant() but nowhere else.  I'm not sure why you are getting downvoted either, because what you are saying is true.  +1

Comment: That's what you can get from @Rizier123  +1 for explanation

Answer (score 0):

The code effect should be *predictable*, and because re-defining TRUE/FALSE will break program logic in gazillion of ways - I'm happy that such things are disabled. Otherwise you will end up in writing a spaghetti code like:

```
if (
     (customer_bought($product_id) && !inverted(TRUE) && !inverted(FALSE)) ||
     (!customer_bought($product_id) && inverted(TRUE) && inverted(FALSE))
   ) {
  send_invoice($client_id);
}
else {
    if ((inverted(TRUE) && !inverted(FALSE)) ||
        (!inverted(TRUE) && inverted(FALSE))
        ) {
       throw new exception('Program is broken - contact developer for assistance');
    }
}
```